# PHP use() function for scope?

Tags: php, syntax, anonymous-function

I have seen code like this:

```
function($cfg) use ($connections) {}
```

but php.net doesn't seem to mention that function. I'm guessing it's related to scope, but how?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`use` is not a function, it's part of the [Closure syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php). It simply makes the specified variables of the outer scope available inside the closure.

```
$foo = 42;

$bar = function () {
    // can't access $foo in here
    echo $foo; // undefined variable
};

$baz = function () use ($foo) {
    // $foo is made available in here by use()
    echo $foo; // 42
}
```

For example:

```
$array = array('foo', 'bar', 'baz');
$prefix = uniqid();

$array = array_map(function ($elem) use ($prefix) {
    return $prefix . $elem;
}, $array);

// $array = array('4b3403665fea6foo', '4b3403665fea6bar', '4b3403665fea6baz');
```

Answer (score 6):

It is telling the anonymous function to make `$connections` (a *parent* variable) available in its scope.

Without it, `$connections` wouldn't be defined inside the function.

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#example-154).

Comment: It should be noted that `$connections` would not be `null`; it would be an undefined variable if it wasn't explicitly imported into the anonymous function's scope with `use ($connections)`.

Answer (score 0):

Just an addition to the answer

```
$bok = fn() => "don't need to use $foo";

echo $bok(); // don't need to use 42
```