# Dependency Injection instead of global variable

Tags: php, function, closures

I have an issue with my code :

```
 public function show($id) {
                $campaign = Campaign::where(function ($query) {
                    $query->where('Status', '=', 'yes')
                            ->orWhere('AppUserId', '=', Auth::user()->AppUserId);
                })->where(function ($query) {
                    $query->where('CampaignId', '=', $id);
                })->get()->toArray();

            }
```

I am getting

> Undefined variable: id

How can i get $id variable value inside the function here :

`$query->where('CampaignId', '=', $id);`

using dependency injection instead of a global variable?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are passing in `$id`.  Your problem is with `$query`, where does that come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `use` to propagate $id in the closure scope:

```
function ($query) use($id)
```

[See also this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7885552/853041)