# Complex php arrays combine (two different structures)

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, merge, array-merge

I don't even know what words to use :)

I have this one array:

```
array(
    0 => array(
        'protein' => 'proteiny',
        'total_fat' => 'total faty',
        'carbohydrates' => 'carbohydrates',
        'food_energy' => 'food energy',
...
```

And another array:

```
1 => array(
    'protein' => 'grams',
    'total_fat' => 'grams',
    'carbohydrates' => 'grams',
    'food_energy' => 'kcals',
...
```

And i want to combine them into a new array in this structure:

```
$newone = array(
        array('slug' => 'protein', 'name' => 'proteiny', 'format' => 'grams'),
        array('slug' => 'total_fat', 'name' => 'total faty', 'format' => 'grams'),
        array('slug' => 'carbohydrates', 'name' => 'carbohydrates', 'format' => 'grams'),
        array('slug' => 'food_energy', 'name' => 'food energy', 'format' => 'kcals'),
    ...
```

IS there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**array_map()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) over the array `$a` with scope [**use($b)**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885513/php-use-function-for-scope) to make the `$newone`. Example:

```
$a = array('protein' => 'proteiny', 'total_fat' => 'total faty', 'carbohydrates' => 'carbohydrates', 'food_energy' => 'food energy');
$b = array('protein' => 'grams', 'total_fat' => 'grams', 'carbohydrates' => 'grams', 'food_energy' => 'kcals');

$newone = array_map(function($val, $slug) use ($b) {
    return array('slug' => $slug, 'name' => $val, 'format' => $b[$slug]);
}, $a, array_keys($a));

print_r($newone);
```

Working [**demo**](https://3v4l.org/OGlTm).

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

How about simple `foreach` loop when `$a` is the first array and `$b` is the second as:

```
foreach($a as $k => $e) {
    $res[] = array('slug' => $k, 'name' => $e, 'format' => $b[$k]);
}
```

Live example: [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/QUkfJ)

Comment: Thank you very much! i didn't which answer to mark as they are both great!