# Laravel when clause is throwing undefined variable

Tags: laravel, select

I am trying to make a conditional where, inside a select statement. It is throwing undefined variable 'class_id'. What is going wrong here. The variable class_id got some value but is throwing 'Undefined variable: class_id'.

```
$class_id = isset($searchData[1]) ? $searchData[1] : '';

\Log::info($class_id);
    
$students = \User::where('role', 'student')
    ->where('fullName', 'like', '%'.$student_name.'%')
    ->orWhere('username', 'like', '%'.$student_name.'%')
    ->orWhere('email', 'like','%'.$student_name.'%')
    ->when($class_id != '',
        function ($q) {
            return $q->where('studentClass', '=', $class_id);
        })
    ->get();
```

Comment: Try `function ($q) use ($class_id)` not a laravel error

Comment: @jewishmoses sorry for my ignorance here, can you please explain a bit more.  Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7885552/11801683

Comment: @jewishmoses is correct. Use the snippet they provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong syntax for [when()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#conditional-clauses). You are using it in the perfect scenario, and you can omit initializing the variable above.

Laravel 5.2 -> 5.5

```php
$class_id = isset($searchData[1]) ? $searchData[1] : '';

$students = \User::where('role','student')
    ->where('fullName','like','%'.$student_name.'%')
    ->orWhere('username','like','%'.$student_name.'%')
    ->orWhere('email','like','%'.$student_name.'%')
    ->when($class_id, function ($query) use ($class_id) {
        return $query->where('studentClass','=', $class_id);
    })->get();
```

Laravel 5.6+

```php
$students = \User::where('role','student')
    ->where('fullName','like','%'.$student_name.'%')
    ->orWhere('username','like','%'.$student_name.'%')
    ->orWhere('email','like','%'.$student_name.'%')
    ->when($searchData[1], function ($query, $class_id) {
        return $query->where('studentClass','=', $class_id);
    })->get();
```

Comment: ERROR: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Type error: Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\MyController::App\Http\Controllers\{closure}(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected in E:\xampp\htdocs\myweb\app\Http\Controllers\MyController.php:737.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#conditional-clauses

Comment: Hi, i am following the exact same thing...  For me the variable $class_id is a numeric value.  I tried hard coded the variable `$class_id=1` right before the select statement and that too throw the sameerror.

Comment: What version of laravel?

Comment: Looks like the syntax changed in between 5.2 and 5.6

Comment: I am using Laravel 5.2.  The link you shared is for DB query, but I am using the Eloquent way. That is only difference.

Comment: No, the issue is that 5.2 does not pass the second argument to the closure

Comment: Also, the Eloquent query builder extends the DB query builder FYI.